# Always filter related fields for logged user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

All my models on the database should be filtered by user, always. I created for all my models a field `owner` which I get the `user` from the request and fill it in when I'm creating the models.

When I go to all urls they are filtered correctly, as well as when I create them onto the database.

But the problem is when I use the html interface to insert a model on the database, all the related items (it doesn't matter the user) are listed on the foreign key field.

**My view**

```
class TransactionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Transaction.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

**My serializer**

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'description',
                  'value', 'account', 'envelope', 'bill',)
```

**My model**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    envelope = models.ForeignKey(Envelope, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='transactions')
```

For example, with those items when I open the page for inserting the data, all the other accounts (which are restricted for user, too) appear on the combo.

How do I filter related fields for the HTML forms?

And how do I validate if related objects are not from other user?

Comment: From where do you get list accounts for Transactions?

Comment: Do you mean by "html interface" the Admin pages?